# Androidhive tutorial modification possible

Tags: php, android, json, listview

Hello and goood day for all, any suggestion how can i modify androidhive show all product in listview to show all search product in listview. i have php code that search student matricID the show all student subject in JSON list.

```
    <?php

$hostname_localhost ="mysql.serverfree.com";
$database_localhost ="u658807642_andr";
$username_localhost ="u658807642_majd";
$password_localhost ="amirah";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
$matricID= $_REQUEST['matricID'];
// get all products from products table
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM tbl_semester") or die(mysql_error());
$order = "SELECT tbl_semester.pid, tbl_semester.matricID, tbl_semester.code, tbl_semester.course, tbl_semester.point, tbl_semester.crdhour, tbl_semester.grdpoint, tbl_semester.reattempt, tbl_semester.grd";
$order .= " FROM tbl_semester WHERE tbl_semester.matricID =  '$matricID'"; 
$result = mysql_query($order);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$response["tbl_semester"] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["matricID"] = $row["matricID"];
    $product["code"] = $row["code"];
    $product["course"] = $row["course"];
    $product["point"] = $row["point"];
    $product["crdhour"] = $row["crdhour"];
    $product["grdpoint"] = $row["grdpoint"];
    $product["reattempt"] = $row["reattempt"];
    $product["grd"] = $row["grd"];


    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["tbl_semester"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
exit;?>
```

can test the result here :

http://miramajdi.bugs3.com/android/getrecord.php?matricID=226629A131
http://miramajdi.bugs3.com/android/getrecord.php?matricID=226629A132

I successfully run androidhive tutorial, but it show all data from database in listview arrange with PID and Product name.

But in my php code, app need to send setup matricID to php, found and send JSON list back to app and display into listview.

```
    package i.uumportal;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SEMESTERcgpa extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView listView1;
Button button1;
Spinner spinner1;
TextView textView1;
TextView textView4;
TextView textView5;

String tUser;
String tPass;
String matricID;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
private String array_spinner[];
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> semesterList;
// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://miramajdi.bugs3.com/android/getrecord.php";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_SEMESTER = "tbl_semester";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_COURSE = "course";
// products JSONArray
JSONArray tbl_semester = null;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_semestercgpa);

       //Declare 
       button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       final TextView textView1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       final TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
       final TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
       Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

       textView4.setText(b.getCharSequence("tuser"));
       textView5.setText(b.getCharSequence("tpass"));

       matricID=textView1.getText().toString();

        //Home button function
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Calculator.class);
                //Create a bundle object
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                //Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle
                b.putString("tuser", textView4.getText().toString());
                b.putString("tpass", textView5.getText().toString());
                //Add the bundle to the intent.
                intent.putExtras(b);
                //start the DisplayActivity
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }});

        semesterList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SEMESTERcgpa.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }



        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("matricID", matricID));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                       tbl_semester = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SEMESTER);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < tbl_semester.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = tbl_semester.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String course = c.getString(TAG_COURSE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_COURSE, course);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        semesterList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SEMESTERcgpa.this,"No record found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                //  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                //          NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                //  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //  startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //Dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            //Updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SEMESTERcgpa.this, semesterList,R.layout.cgpalist_main, new String[] { TAG_PID,TAG_COURSE},new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.course });
                listView1.setAdapter(adapter);// setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

        }

    }}
```

As can see, i used intent from before send matricID to this activity then display into texview4, then set String matricID equal to text4.

matricID will compare to JSON get. I dont get error, but fail in emulator. Need advice or sample code can match and work with above php.

Comment: Just figure it out, mistake declare TextView with EditText cause unxpected error